# VS Code (circa 1.80) terminal partially covered by a black box. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

It covers up a section of the terminal but I can still type on it.

I'm guessing its a visual bug.

[image: screenshot of VS Code terminal with black box]

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times, but to no avail. There's also not a lot of information on this online either.

Answer (score 3):

This is a recent bug with VS Code 1.80 related to the [new terminal image support feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80#_image-support):

- [Terminal full black #187198](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/187198)
- (duplicate) [Black Screen on Terminal
  #187367](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/187367)
- (duplicate) [Integrated Terminal fully Black
  #187382](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/187382)

The issue can be temporarily fixed by putting the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"terminal.integrated.enableImages": false
```

A fix has been made which will be released in 1.80.1: [Require canvas/webgl use to enable image support #187635](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/187635).

<strike>One user has reported that they still observe the issue in 1.80.1 ([here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/187198#issuecomment-1636356094))</strike>. Turns out that that's [a separate issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/187772).

[Apparently](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/14v6i3x/comment/jrbh7cg/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), the problem can be fixed for one time by force-quitting and restarting VS Code, but the problem comes back every time the terminal is killed.